# How to change user rol after buying in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

thank you for any of you guys wanted to help me, I just want to know how to change the user role in WordPress when users buy something. I'm using WooCommerce. Regards

Comment: which role do you want to assign to users? are you trying to do it manually or need to do it via coding like when the user buys something their role change automatically? or admin will change the user's role ... please clarify that and also if you are trying to do it by code please show your code and what have you tried  so far to achieve it..

Comment: Hey brother, thanks for answering,  and yes, It has to be automatic, I can change the user role manually but it takes processes so slowly, so when user sing up, their role is a buyer and what I need it's like right after customer buy-in WooCommerce, the user Role change automatically for another one that is called agent. Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use Woocommerce action hooks. check my below code.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'change_user_role_afte_buying' );
function change_user_role_afte_buying( $order_id ) {

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();

    $products_to_check = array( '1', '2', '3' ); // your product ids for checking someting buy

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        if ( $order->user_id > 0 && in_array( $item['product_id'], $products_to_check ) ) {
            
            $user = new WP_User( $order->user_id ); // get user Object
            $user->remove_role( 'customer' ); // remove old role
            $user->add_role( 'new-role' ); // add new role
            break;  // Exit the loop

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey bro, thanks for answering, super great your code but It didn't work for me, I'll leave a URL note where I explain how I use it. Thank you.
URL: https://www.miblocdenotas.com/368354

Comment: Buyer and Agent roles are already in the system? also, check my edits.

Comment: Yes brother, if a person comes on the website, this one has a visitor role, and when they sing up, automatically change to Buyer role... when a user is a Buyer means he is already in the system. And roles are already set up in the system.

Comment: Is the new role also available in the system I mean Agent role?